# How long before GoogleBot times out?

Tags: seo, phantomjs, googlebot

**Background**

I'm currently setting up SEO indexing for a dynamic website using Google's #!-approach through a combination of proxies and PhantomJS. Our web app hosts not only our own application, but any number of applications that have been contributed by 3rd parties. As I am not in control of these applications (and thus their load time) I am now facing two options when dealing with GoogleBot queries:

1. Cache generated HTML and return the cached response to GoogleBot. Refresh the cache on every GoogleBot-request, but return the stale response
2. Use a time-based caching mechanism. On expiry, GoogleBot gets a newly generated response

Clearly I would prefer to go for (2), but I worry that GoogleBot will time out before reading the crawled HTML.

**Question**

How long before a GoogleBot request times out?

Comment: I wouldn't try to squeeze phantomjs in for immediate generation of new static content. This will directly impact your page rank even if you don't hit the timeout, because the slower your page responds the lower you will be in the search results. It is better to run a cron job to refresh the cache or do something probabilistic.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be safe to then let the GoogleBot trigger the indexing, but return the currentVersion-1 response, i.e. return the cached response and refresh the cache shortly after the request has been served?

Comment: That depends on your application. If the updated information should be visible and searchable, but changes a lot, then only if the previous snapshot is not too old. Negative example: Popular blog with a lot of comments doesn't need to be constantly up to date, because the blog content doesn't change that often and comments are not business critical. Regardless, it would be better to trigger the indexing through cron or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Google will penalize web-pages with a slow response-time, so better is to proactively generate and cache content before Google comes to fetch it.

**Long answer**

As pointed out by @ArtjomB in the comments-section, (2) will never be an option, since Google will penalize pages with a long response time. (1) is an option only if indexing information that is non time-sensitive.

The better alternative would be the unstated third option: A cron-job that proactively re-indexes and caches content before any GoogleBot fetches, although that clearly comes at a cost, since X% of re-indexes might end up never being fetched by GoogleBot.